# how to check if number is octal and contains up to 6 digits in java

Tags: java

How to check if number is octal and contains up to 6 digits in java?

I was told this.. can anyone explain this piece by piece?

```
    ^0[1-7][0-7]*$
```

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: that's a regular expression. read one of the thousands of tutorials on this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex checks if the number is octal, but it does *not* check that the number contains up to six octal digits.

In order to ensure that the number contains up to six octal digits you need to modify the regex as follows:

```
^0[1-7][0-7]{0,5}$
```

The `{0,5}` part says that the number of digits following the initial digit is from zero to five. Combined with the initial non-zero digit the total number will be from one to six, inclusive.

The meaning of the expression can be fully understood by following the [*regex `Pattern` reference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation. The only tricky part is using the `[1-7]` part following the leading zero. It's there to ensure that numbers such as `00` do *not* match this regex.

Answer (score 0):

`^` assert position at start of the string

`0` matches the character `0` literally

`[1-7]` a single character in the range between `1` and `7`

`[0-7]*` a character in the range between `0` and `7`, an unlimited amount of times (greedy)

`$` assert position at end of the string

This is called a regex or regular expression. However, this particular regular expression will not match up to 6 digits long. It will only check if it is an octal number which starts with 0 and is then followed by a number between 1 and 7. Finally that is followed by an unlimited amount of digits, each one between 0 and 7

Comment: what do you mean it 'will not match up to 6 digits long - the '*' is a greedy operator - it means as many 0-7's as there is before the end of string '$'

Comment: If you enter 7 digits it will still allow because no limit

Comment: Apologies - I didn't pay attention to the {} operator. @dasblinkenlight answer is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

An octal number always begins with a '0'. That is the trademark of an octal descriptor according to the [Java language specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). The second character of an octal number must always be between 1 and 7 inclusive - hence the `[1-7]` after which you can have any combination of octal characters - 0 to 7 which explains the `[0-7]*`. It's pretty much the same as looking at a decimal number - 0001 is still just 1. However, because you are looking at octal digits you are constrained to the first digit being zero and the second at least being significant - hence the 1 to 7.